# Linux API to get Hugepagesize

Tags: c++, c, linux

How can I get the the Hugepagesize value in /proc/meminfo

Hugepagesize:       2048 kB

without parsing /proc/meminfo?

I can get the regular page size by using

```
#include <unistd.h>
long sz = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
```

Is there a sysconf argument that will provide Hugepagesize?

Comment: What is wrong with parsing `/proc/meminfo`? You'll need to ge the huge page size only once in your program. Can't you parse `/proc/meminfo` at startup - and it is really easy to parse.... Don't forget that `/proc/` is a pseudo-file-system (it is *not* on the disk, no real I/O involved) and reading it is really cheap.

Comment: Thanks. I can parse /proc/meminfo, I was not quite worried about the cost. I was just wondering if parsing /proc/meminfo was the best way to go given that there is a sysconf API.

Comment: The very notion of *hugepagesize* is Linux (and probably x86-64) specific, and Linux provides `/proc/` as the *preferred* way to query such information from the kernel, so go and parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Linux exposes a programmatic API for getting that value form userspace.  But I agree with the comments here... /proc/meminfo is a solid alternative.

You can look at the kernel code in $KERNEL/fs/proc/meminfo.c to see how it's derived:

```
> meminfo_proc_show()
  > hugetlb_report_meminfo()
    > 1UL << (huge_page_order(h) + PAGE_SHIFT - 10) // actual value
```